# How to decide when to pass parameter & when not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, arguments

Can anyone tell me how do we know when we need to pass the parameter & when not? For example in below code `click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)` I am not passing any parameter & directly giving the index argument still the code is working. On the other hand `changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)` I have to pass event parameter to make the code work. Here I am getting confuse how to decide when to pass parameter & when not.

````
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: [
     { id: 'user1', name: 'Royal1', age: 20},
     { id: 'user2', name: 'Royal2', age: 21},
     { id: 'user3', name: 'Royal3', age: 23}
    ],
    other: 'some other value',
    showPersons: false
  }

  nameChangedHandler = (event, id) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    })

    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    }
   person.name = event.target.value
   const persons = [...this.state.persons]
   persons[personIndex] = person

    this.setState({ persons: persons})
  }

  deletePersonHandler = (personIndex) => {
    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons.splice(personIndex, 1);
    this.setState({persons: persons})
  }


  togglePersonsHandler = () => {
      const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
      this.setState({showPersons: !doesShow});
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      font: 'inherit',
      border: '1px solid blue',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }

    let persons = null;

    if (this.state.showPersons) {
      persons = <div>
      {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
        return <Person
        click={() => this.deletePersonHandler(index)}
        name={person.name}
        age={person.age}
        key={person.id}
        changed={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, person.id)} />
      })}
      </div>
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi I am React App</h1>
      <p>This is really working!</p>
      <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}>Switch Name</button>
      {persons}
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events like onClick, onChange and others will pass an "event" parameter (could be event, e, or whatever name you give to it) by default to your event handler.

The thing is, if you want to pass custom parameters too, the handler will receive them but this default event won't be accesible, unless you pass it too.

You can see an example with 3 different scenarios [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-chatterjee-9y3lh?file=/src/Component.js:106-489)

- Receive only the event. No need to pass it:

```
onClick={() => this.nameChangedHandler()} />
```

- Receive both the event, plus custom parameters (id is state in this example)

```
onClick={(event) => this.nameChangedHandler(event, id)} />
```

- Pass only a custom parameter, but don't receive event

```
onClick={() => this.nameChangedHandler(id)} />
```

Comment: I am getting your answer. So you mean if I just needed event or any other single parameter then I don't need to pass it. On the other hand in this case I need event+id so I had to pass because I wanted to call multiple parameter?

Comment: Almost. If you need a custom parameter you have to pass it (added scenario on 3rd example). If you only need event then you don't have to pass it (first example). If you want both event and custom parameter, you pass both (second example)

Comment: Sorry asking you again but I am actually not a js expert. What do you mean by custom parameter? why are you calling id as a custom parameter? and why event is not a custom parameter?

Comment: It's ok. "id" comes from your state right? That is a "custom" parameter in this scenario. "event" is the default object you receive when you use an event handler: onChange/onEvent will dispatch this event by default and your event handler will receive it. You can read more about the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#:~:text=Event%20objects,provide%20extra%20features%20and%20information.), this will be passed automatically. It contains all info about the event that was executed recently, including type of event target name(button)etc

Comment: Thanks I got it, this will be last question. So the event is default and will be passed automatically then why we had to pass it as a parameter? and why we didn't pass id as a parameter although it was a custom parameter? (we are using id directly as an argument)

Comment: That is a little bit more tricky to answer in a comment. It has to do with the way your handler function is called from onClick. You're passing a function that calls nameChangeHandler. If you used "id" as an argument, it won't be the "id" in your state, but the function expects another id passed as argument. But you don't have control over this function (you can't pass id). The only thing that will be passed is the "event". onChange will know that you want event passed automatically  so you don't have to pass it. But if you passed a custom parameter that overwrites the event.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) (from the React docs).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you pass as the event handler is going to get called with the event object. Imagine the following cases:

- `const noParams = () => { ... };`

  - `onClick={noParams}` -> `noParams(event)` ✅
  - `onClick={() => noParams()}` -> `noParams()` ✅
- `const nonEventParams = (thing) => { ... };`

  - `onClick={noParams}` -> `nonEventParams(event)` ❌
  - `onClick={() => nonEventParams(thing)}` -> `nonEventParams(thing)` ✅
- `const usesEvent = (event) => { ... };`

  - `onClick={usesEvent}` -> `usesEvent(event)` ✅
  - `onClick={(event) => usesEvent(event)}` -> `usesEvent(event)` ✅
- `const mixedParams = (event, thing) => { ... }`

  - `onClick={mixedParams}` -> `mixedParams(event)` ❌
  - `onClick={(event) => mixedParams(event, thing)}` -> `mixedParams(event, thing)` ✅

If your callback requires nothing, or *only* the event, you can pass it directly. In all other cases you need to pass a function that proxies the event and any other parameters to your callback.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the function you will be calling and what parameters its expecting.

Assume we have the following code

```
const doSomething = () => {}
const doSomethingBasedOnEvent = (event, otherParam) => {
 // do something with event and otherParam
}
const doSomethingBasedOnCustomParams = (param1, param2) => {}
const doSomethingJustWithEvent = event

// native event handlers (event handlers that are attached to dom elements) always pass an event parameter to the event listener
// here the event parameter will be passed directly to doSomethingJustWithEvent
<button onClick={doSomethingJustWithEvent} />

// if you want to pass other params
<button onClick={() => doSomethingBasedOnEvent(event, otherParam)} />
// A custom component callback might pass some custome events
<CustomComponent onSomeCustomEvent={(param1, param2, param3) => doSomethingBasedOnCustomParams(param1, param2)} />

// if your function does not need any parameters or just takes the exact same parameters as the handler you can pass it directly 
<CustomComponent onSomeCustomEvent={doSomething} />
```

The bottom line it just depends upon the function you need to call and whats the parameters it does need