# Difference between writing inline function methods vs normal method inside Render function React js

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

i am finding difficult understanding difference between call a fuction onClick of button and pass arguments to methods inside render here my question is why we use `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>` vs `<button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button>` what does using arrow inside of it means, i know it indicates a function,while looping i want to send arguments that i am able to do only using `<button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button>` method but i am able to do it using  `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>` method,could somebody explain me these differences.

```
 handleDel = (id) => {
    this.setState({ todo: this.state.todo.filter((item) => item.id !== id) });
  };
```

and why are we using again arrow function  method above except for binding because i have already used while declaring onclick `<button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button>` and cant we pass parameter like this `<button onClick={(para)=>this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button>` instead of

```
 handleDel = (id) => {
   
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decide when to pass parameter & when not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632290/how-to-decide-when-to-pass-parameter-when-not)

Comment: the link gives me clear explanation of how to pass parameter and arguments but why we use parenthesis in onClick <button onClick{()=>this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button> vs <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button> i want to know the difference between these two

Comment: That's *arrow function* syntax. You should run through a basic ES6 tutorial before trying to add JSX and the React API on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, we need to pass a function as the event handler, please refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to know more about handling events in React. So in either of the cases we are passing a function, but there's a slight difference.

- When you don't want to send any custom arguments to the event handler function we use `<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>`. This way by default `event` object is being sent to the handler which can be used on the need basis.

```
const handleClick = (event) => { ..... }

//....some code
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
```

- But when you want to send some parameters to the handler function, then we are wrap the actual event handler in an anonymous function like `() => this.handleClick(argument)`.

```
const handleClick = (data) => { ..... }

//....some code
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(argument)}>Click</button>
```

Along with the arguments, if we want to pass event object then we can do the like below

```
const handleClick = (event, data) => { ..... }

//....some code
<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, argument)}>Click</button>
```