# How do I pass parameters in a function with useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, function, render, use-state

How do I pass parameters in a function with useState?

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const addNumber = (number) => setCount(count + number)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<TouchableOpacity  onPress = {addNumber(1)}>
 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

"Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: try `const addNumber = (number) => setCount(oldVal=>oldVal + number)` and change `onPress` like this `<TouchableOpacity  onPress = {()=>{addNumber(1)}}> `

Comment: You need a function that returns a function, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632536/3001761.

Comment: aaahh.. a Function that returns a function ! Thanks for the link very useful 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const addNumber = (number) => setCount((prev) => prev + number)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<TouchableOpacity  onPress = {()=>{addNumber(1)}}>
 
</TouchableOpacity>
```