# Are these two JavaScript statements equivalent under functional programming rules in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there some functional programming rule that says that these two things are the same?

That is, I'm passing a function as a attribute in a React program and I was using the second version with the first parameter passed in.  Just out of curiosity, I replaced with just passing the function and my app still worked but I'm confused why.

(to be extra clear, onFavoriteToggle is a function)

```
  <SpeakerFavorite
    favorite={favorite}
    onFavoriteToggle={onFavoriteToggle}
  />
```

compared to

```
  <SpeakerFavorite
      favorite={favorite}
      onFavoriteToggle={(fun) => {onFavoriteToggle(fun)}}
  />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decide when to pass parameter & when not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632290/how-to-decide-when-to-pass-parameter-when-not)

Comment: And what do you mean by *"functional programming rule"*?

Comment: [Yes, as long as `onFavoriteToggle()` takes only one parameter and it's going to be called with only one parameter, then eta reduction makes them equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878788/)

Comment: @VLAZ, Does my example fall under the category of Identity functions? I know without the parameter it does, not sure if with the parameter is the same.

Comment: No, it's not an identity. An identity function has different semantics - it's `x => x`. However, with equal parameters, `x => fn(x)` is reducible to just `fn`. For example, `["1", "2", "3"].map(x => Number(x))` is the same as `["1", "2", "3"].map(Number)`. However, `["1", "2", "3"].map(x => parseInt(x))` is *not* the same as ["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt)` because because of the different arity of the function and how it's going to be called. See [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262427)

Comment: These _can_ be equivalent but are not universally so. For example if the example is actually `this` specific, if the function takes a number of arguments etc. To avoid ambiguity and problems when underlying interfaces change, I would advise against the first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(fun) => {onFavoriteToggle(fun)}
```

is a "proxy" function that simply calls another function with the same argument it receives. In this case, serves no purpose and actually may harm your app performance in extreme cases.

However, if `SpeakerFavorite` calls this "proxy" function passed as `onFavoriteToggle` prop with not one, but two arguments, the second argument would now get lost, as "proxy" function only receives one argument. This may lead to hard to debug errors.

If you don't need to do anything else, just pass the function without "proxy" in between.