# What is the difference between arrow function being passed vs function just as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6, callback

What are the differences between these two implementations of what should be the same logic?

```
// Method 1

const myCallback = (foo) => foo;
afterCallback(myCallback);
   
// Method 2

const myCallback = (foo) => foo;
afterCallback(() => myCallback);
```

Comment: In the second one `myCallback` isn't actually called back? In the second one you ignore the argument to the callback entirely? Maybe have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63632290/3001761.

Comment: I presume you mean `afterCallback(() => myCallback())`? You are missing the `()`

Answer (score 0):

The key difference is how your callback functions were constructed. If you look at the first code fragment:

```
afterCallback(myCallback);
```

We can presume that `afterCallback` expects a function and calls it - something like this:

```
function afterCallback(fn) {
    // Do stuff
    fn(stuff);
}
```

So that means that when we pass in `myCallback`, the code being run looks like:

```
myCallback(stuff)
```

In your second example, however, you do have a function - but it's simply returning another function. The second example is equivalent to:

```
afterCallback(function() { 
    return function(foo) {
        return foo;
    }
});
```

As you can see, a function is being returned, not actually the result of calling it. That means that `myCallback` is never run. You need to call the returned function:

```
afterCallback(function() {
    return (function(foo) {
        return foo;
    })();
});
```

I've just used an IIFE here for simplicity. This would look like the following when arrow function syntax is used:

```
afterCallback(() => myCallback());
```

Change the parameterisation as necessary; but the problem was your first returned function was returning a second function but not calling it.