# Difference between onClick={function()} and onClick={()=>function()} in React

Tags: reactjs

when trying to call this function onClick,

`function changeProfile(e){setProfilePic(e)}`

when I use
`onClick={changeProfile(props)}`, it calls the function whenever the page is loaded, and doesn't work properly as it calls all the props at once even the ones that are not called.
`onClick={()=>{changeProfile(props)` this works exactly how I imagined, calling only the component that is clicked. What is the difference between the two and when do I use the specific method of `{()=>function}`??

I know that it works now, but what is the exact difference between the two?

Comment: `onClick={changeProfile(props)}` is **calling** `changeProfile` with `props` and passing the **return value** as the `onClick` prop. `onClick={() => changeProfile(props)}` is passing a function as the `onClick` prop. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632536/3001761. Note this is nothing to do with React or JSX really, what's inside `{}` is just a regular JS expression.

Answer (score 1):

`onClick={()=>{changeProfile(props)` will register an event handler to the click event.

`onClick={changeProfile(props)}` will run when it is encountered in the code. This is why it occurs on the page load.